# How to automount an external drive to hold ~/LIbrary[/Developer[/CoreSimulator]]

Tags: macos, bash, mount, sudo

Xcode simulators as usual multiples and expands
turning ~/Library into a dumpster

now on 256gb drive there is no space to install xcode 14.2 and i;m thinking to resolve the issue extensively
buying an external 0.5tb drive

How could I auto mount it to ~/Library
upon login and migrate all the stuff that's currently in ~/Library to it?

could I just mount it in ~/.profile ?
I assume user interaction is needed if I sudo mount anything and .profile / .bashrc was meant to run without UI.

thanks

PS i've eased the pain somehow blowing off tvos and watchoff caches

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches//dyld/19G73/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-1*

which in turn led to this question

[How much space does xcode 14.2 really need?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407930/how-much-space-does-xcode-14-2-really-need)

UPD2 /CoreSimulator/Devices/udid/plistishere
you can go through the list of udids and check plists in there to
see if you actually use or plan to that particular simulator for
ipod torch 3rd generation :^)

Comment: ~/Library hold browser caches, among much more. Moving it to an external drive will probably slow down browsers and more.

Comment: i'm considering a rather speedy thunderbolt 3 ssd drive as opposed to a molasses like usb-c drive used for backups

Comment: Does not have to be library, I can drill further down the tree: 98G ~/Library/Developer

Comment: the main offender:  60G /Users/Anton.Tropasko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator