# How much space does xcode 14.2 really need?

Tags: macos, xcode

$ df -H
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5    251G    11G    39G    23%  488329 2447612991    0%   /

and yet "you have no space to install xcode"

39 gig is no longer enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, when it says that you haven't got enough disk space to be install Xcode, you need to free up more space in order to complete the installation.

As far as I remember approx. 40-45 GB of free space is needed to complete the install.

Comment: We’re telling our developers to have 50 GB free based on their lack of cleaning the old simulators and items off the disk before doing the install.